# Display Array in Twig

Tags: php, model-view-controller, twig

I am trying to display array passed in twig. But it is not working. I have used following syntax:

Controller:

```
public function profileAction()
    {
        $data = ['name' => 'Manish'];

        View::renderTemplate('User/profile.html',$data);
    }
```

Twig view:

```
{{ data.name }}
```

When doing var_dump in cpntroller. I get following:

```
array(1) { ["name"]=> string(6) "Manish" }
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: this which framework symfony ??

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Comment: @ArtOsi the data is not displaying.

Comment: What is `View`?

Comment: @Robert No, i am not using any framework. I have used twig library

Comment: okay, can you refer this http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2015/08/31/using-the-twig-templating-engine-in-php/

Comment: Just `{{ name }}`

Comment: @u_mulder it is working. thank  you :)

Comment: Now you should understand __why__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.name` don't exist in the view

Change Twig view to:

```
{{ name }}
```

Comment: what if the var_dump is in following format:
array(1) { [0]=> array(16) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" [0]=> string(1) "4" ["fname"]=> string(7) "Manish " [1]=> string(7) "Manish " ["lname"]=> string(8) "Maharjan" [2]=> string(8) "Maharjan" ["address"]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(25) "itsupport@bergernepal.com" [4]=> string(25) "itsupport@bergernepal.com" ["phone_number"]=> NULL [5]=> NULL ["password"]=> string(32) "25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad" [6]=> string(32) "25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad" ["companyid"]=> string(1) "9" [7]=> string(1) "9" } }

Comment: if $data has array(1) { [0]=> array(16) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4", .... you need iterate over it in the template

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: View::renderTemplate('User/profile.html',['data' => $data]);

Twing template
{% for dt in data %}
        {{ dt.name }}
{% endfor %}